# what's the difference between machine hardware name and processor type

Tags: linux-kernel

I know that my machine hardware name is i686 and processor type is i686 due to my Linux output. But I have no idea why they are the same. I want to know what's the difference between machine hardware name and processor type.

Comment: Please clarify your question. At the moment you seem to be asking why i686 is the same as i686. What exactly do you mean by "machine hardware name"?

Comment: OK, you mean in the output of `uname`?

Comment: I want to know what machine hardware name is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained more clearly in `info uname`:

```
`-m'
`--machine'
     Print the machine hardware name (sometimes called the hardware
     class or hardware type).

`-p'
`--processor'
     Print the processor type (sometimes called the instruction set
     architecture or ISA).  Print `unknown' if the kernel does not make
     this information easily available, as is the case with Linux
     kernels.
```

So, the hardware name is the CPU [architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_architectures), while the processor type is the name of the [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) used. To quote from wikipedia:

> Instruction set architecture is distinguished from the microarchitecture, which is the set of processor design techniques used to implement the instruction set. Computers with different microarchitectures can share a common instruction set. For example, the Intel Pentium and the AMD Athlon implement nearly identical versions of the x86 instruction set, but have radically different internal designs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dmidecode` to get some more information about your system and hardware.

```
sudo dmidecode -s STRING-KEYWORD
```

With the following list of keywords:

```
bios-vendor
bios-version
bios-release-date
system-manufacturer
system-product-name
system-version
system-serial-number
system-uuid
baseboard-manufacturer
baseboard-product-name
baseboard-version
baseboard-serial-number
baseboard-asset-tag
chassis-manufacturer
chassis-type
chassis-version
chassis-serial-number
chassis-asset-tag
processor-family
processor-manufacturer
processor-version
processor-frequency
```